# Why can't VSCode's TypeScript checking find these particular imported types?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vite, vite-tsc

I have a frustrating situation in VS Code where in my Vite/Vue frontend, certain types imported from my Node backend cannot be found.

In my frontend:

[image]

The yellow wiggly underlines indicate that it can find the top two imports, although they're not used. The bottom two give this kind of error:

> Module '"@backend/models/orders"' has no exported member 'KoordinatesOrderBody'. Did you mean to use 'import KoordinatesOrderBody from "@backend/models/orders"' instead?ts(2614)

```js
export type KoordinatesOrderBody = {
    crs: string;
    ...
};

export interface NewOrderBody {
    layerIds: string[];
}

export interface OrderModel
    extends Model<
        InferAttributes<OrderModel>,
        InferCreationAttributes<OrderModel>
    > {
...
}
```

In the frontend's `ts.config.json` (referenced in `tsconfig.json`):

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue", "../backend/src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@backend/*": ["../backend/src/*"],
    },
    "rootDir": "..",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true
  }
}
```

Elsewhere in my frontend I am importing types from the backend without issue.

This situation makes no sense to me, and feels like it might be a bug. Is there a way to force VS Code to dump its cache or something?

Running `vue-tsc` on the frontend does not report this issue, so I think it must be specific to VS Code's built-in typechecking (if that's what this is).

Answer (score 0):

You could just import all from one import statement

```
import { type a, type b, type c } from '@lib'
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that would fix this issue?